# QueryDSL Join multiple tables and subqueries

Tags: mysql, jpa, spring-boot, entitymanager, querydsl

I am new to queryDSL. My application have a complex search page with more number of search fields. Can anyone help me in forming a QueryDSL query for the below one:

```
select pt.pID
     , ct.name 
  from PARENT_TABLE pt 
  left 
  join CHILD_TABLE ct 
    on pt.pID = ct.cID 
 where pt.pID = '1000'
```

By using Predicates any() method I tried to join but with that i am unable to fetch the actual data. Without configuring entity manager is it possible to solve this?

Please let me know if more info needed.
Thanks in advance

Comment: The above query is working for u? Or u would need to convert above query in queryDsl.

Comment: I need code for the above query in QueryDSL. I am unaware of QueryDSL joins and I need help to form code in joining the tables. The query I pasted above is my requirement. @Pankaj .  Thank you very much

Comment: Is it possible  to do without an Entitymanager or EntityManagerFactory. My application is using spring boot which doesnt have persistence.xml file.

Comment: You need to be more specific. Querydsl has multiple modules. Do you want to use Querydsl with JPA or without?

Comment: @TimoWestkämper My application is using Spring boot . I want to use QueryDSL with JPA. Thanks.